# How can I get a streaming effect like a pipe open with IPC::Run3?

Tags: perl, stdin, io-redirection

Given the following code, the user will see it printed 3 times, one time a second "Hello World!".

```
#!/bin/perl
$| = 1;
use feature ':5.10';
use strict;
use warnings;

use constant PERL_SCRIPT => '$|=1; foreach (0..3) {say "World!"; sleep 1}';

open ( my $h, '-|', '/bin/perl', '-wE', PERL_SCRIPT() ) or die $!; 
while (<$h>) {
  print "Hello $_";
}
```

How can I achieve this same effect with `IPC::Run3`? Note, I don't want buffering. I want this to stream.

Why am I using `IPC::Run3`? I want to stdin to be pointed to `/dev/null`. And, I don't want to have to have to do the actual redirection with another shell exec.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you could simply use the following along with your existing code if you don't otherwise need STDIN in the parent.

```perl
open(STDIN, '<', '/dev/null') or die $!;
```

I don't think you can with IPC::Run3, but you can with IPC::Run.

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

run [ $^X, -wE => PERL_SCRIPT ],
   \undef,
   sub { print "Hello $_[0]" };
```

If you wanted to use a pipe, you could use the following:

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( start );
use Symbol   qw( gensym );

my $h =
   start [ $^X, -wE => PERL_SCRIPT ],
      \undef,
      '>pipe', my $pipe = gensym;

print "Hello $_" while <$pipe>;

$h->finish();
```

(You can't use `run` because that waits for the child to finish.)

Comment: Updated my answer.